# vb.net setting custom class property from text file ReadLine, string cannot be converted to array of string

Tags: vb.net, string, class, file-io

I'm new to custom classes. Here is my class definition:

```
Public Class game
    Private strName As String()

    Property name As String()
        Get
            Return strName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String())
            strName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And here is my code to read from a file and create an instance of "game"

```
Public Sub loadGames()
    Dim game As New game

    Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(gameFolder)
    Dim fs As IO.FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.gemui")
    Dim f As IO.FileInfo
    For Each f In fs
        Dim path As String = f.FullName
        Dim fi As New FileInfo(path)
        Dim sr As StreamReader = fi.OpenText()
        Dim s As String = ""
        While sr.EndOfStream = False
            game.name = sr.ReadLine() '"Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'."
            MsgBox(sr.ReadLine()) 'shows a message box with exactly what I expect to see
        End While
        sr.Close()

    Next
End Sub
```

**game.name = sr.ReadLine()** is the problem.  *"Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'."*

Comment: what you want to do? you are trying to implicitly cast string to array ?

Comment: the `Name` property of your class was declared as Array-of-string, but the `text.ReadLine()` method returns `string`. Consider to define the `Name` property as string or use: `text.ReadLine().Split(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in your class definition you are not declaring strings, you are declaring arrays of strings. Corrected code is:

```
Public Class game
    Private strName As String

    Property name As String
        Get
            Return strName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            strName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

or more simply in .net 4.0+

```
Public Class game
    Property name As String
End Class
```

in this case the private variable is called _name